# Ubuntu 16.04 won't run from USB because of internal error

Tags: live-usb

I am trying to run Ubuntu 16.04 from USB that passes Ubuntu disk defect check but it keeps having an internal error. Current OS windows 10 came with ASUS G11cd.

Comment: Tell us more about your configuration. Windows 10 is on an internal hard disk or SSD? Windows 10 boots fine, yes? Ubuntu is on a USB disk drive, or USB key, or? How did you install Ubuntu? What's the exact error message?

Comment: windows 10 is internal C. Ubuntu is a .iso on a uui formatted usb3. the error is titled compiz-crashed-with-SIGILL

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu from the USB? Is it a flash drive? I don't understand uui formatted. It just sounds like you built Ubuntu to a flash drive, and it didn't go right. Burn Ubuntu to a DVD and you won't have any trouble booting it. Please report back.

Comment: should i format the dvdr as a dvd then or like a usb (live)? the idea here is to try ubuntu 1st, not to replace win10.

Comment: installed from dvdr and is running good. ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion in the comments, burn Ubuntu to a DVD and you won't have any trouble booting it. If you need help burning a DVD, please refer to:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 3):

Try switching the USB stick to a different USB port -- especially if you have both USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports on your computer. Sometimes one will work long enough to start a boot, but stop being able to read the stick partway through.

You can also try going into your bios and enabling Legacy USB.

Comment: I will try the legacy USB...
windows 10 is internal C. Ubuntu is a .iso on a uui formatted usb3. the error is titled compiz-crashed-with-SIGILL